# Any program to change Date Created of Videos to actual EXIF data?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, os-x

I had a look at this topic [Is there a free program to (batch) change photo file's date to match EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/is-there-a-free-program-to-batch-change-photo-files-date-to-match-exif?newreg=aea3ab82272a49d8b50f77dc884eae59) and it was very useful to change my photos' **Date Created** values to their rightful date in EXIF, but unfortunately the videos are not affected...

I am using EXIFTOOL on my MAC OSX Sierra with the following command

`exiftool -r '-DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate' directoryname`

Any ideas?

---

*EDIT* I added this image to help explain.

I'm trying to copy the actual date creation in the EXIF data to the remaining attributes which are used when sorting in my MAC

[image: d]

So the following listing options are updated too :

[image]

Comment: Is your goal to set the file's "creation" time or its "last modified" time?

Comment: The exact opposite, the file's creation time based on actual EXIF data (when I actually took the video). When I currently export it from my Photos app on mac, the date created is in 2016, but right-click -> info shows 2012.

Comment: Several times in your question you state incorrectly what you are trying to achieve. In fact, what you want is not to set the file's "creation" time, but to set the file's "last modified" time to that which is recorded in the EXIF as CreationDate.

Comment: @osullic Under finder's listing, Date Created and Date Modified and Date Added are all the same, but Date Created in the EXIF data is completely different. Hence the confusion in terms.

Comment: Date Created and Date Modified and Date Added might be the same for some file (or set of files). But these are all distinct file properties, and I'm just saying that you need to be clear (both for yourself and for others) about which one you want to change.

Comment: Question has been answered.@osullic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to set the file's "creation" time, but you are using `FileModifyDate` in your command, which presumably is for setting a file's "last modified" date. I think you should be using `FileCreateDate` instead.

I am not *that* familiar with ExifTool, but I would suggest you at least read the [FAQ](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html). See in particular FAQ 16 "Some files not renamed" - I realise you are not renaming files, but this question does say, "By default, ExifTool only processes writable file types when any tag is being written and a directory name is specified on the command line", which may apply to your use case.

Comment: That worked, but i used `exiftool -r '-CreationDate>FileModifyDate' directoryname` thanks

Comment: Here's what worked for me on Mac OS: `exiftool -r '-EXIF:DateTimeOriginal>FileModifyDate' '/path/to/folder` [credit](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/69193)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late, but nonetheless I recently had the same problem with my iPhone created videos. My iPhone writes the creation date to the `CreationDate` tag but Lightroom ignores this tag and expects `DateTimeOriginal`.

I therefore wrote a short Bash script to set `DateTimeOriginal` from `CreationDate` if `DateTimeOriginal` does not exist yet (to avoid unwanted modifications):

```
#!/bin/bash

# If (video) file(s) miss EXIF tag DateTimeOriginal, copy it from CreationDate.
this=`basename "$0"`
if [[ "$#" == "0" ]]; then
    echo "Copies EXIF tag CreationDate to DateTimeOriginal if DateTimeOriginal is missing."
    echo "Usage: $this [OPTIONS] *FILE*"
    echo "    While *FILE* may be one or file more files or directories."
    echo "    By default original files will be overwritten. To keep a backup file, use -no_overwrite_original."
    echo "    For further options see exiftool --help."
    echo "Example: $this -r -ext mov -ext mp4 ."
    echo "    Processes all MOV and MP4 video files in this directory including subdirectories."
    exit 1
fi
overwrite_original="-overwrite_original"
if [[ "$*" == *-no_overwrite_original* ]]; then
    overwrite_original=""
fi
exiftool -if 'not $DateTimeOriginal' '-DateTimeOriginal<CreationDate' -P $overwrite_original $*
```